# How can I hook up a simple MOSFET to amplify the PWM signal from Arduino?

Tags: arduino, amplifier, speakers

I have an 8-ohm 1/2 Watt speaker I'd like to hook up to the Arduino. I'm currently hooking up the gate of a FQP30N06L MOSFET to the PWM output of the Arduino. I've tied the drain to Vcc (5V) and the source to the (+) speaker terminal, with (-) speaker terminal to ground. I also have a 10Kohm resistor from the MOSFET gate to ground.

This gives a pretty good volume output, but I'm worried about two things:

- Doesn't a speaker act as a short for DC current? I'm afraid this could fry the MOSFET.
- This seems to run a DC current component thru the speaker, which I'd like to remove.
- There is a lot of high-frequency "ringing" (bad audio quality)

I've tried other things, but the speaker just isn't loud enough. For example, putting a resistor in series with the speaker makes the sound too quiet. Also,  using a DC-blocking capacitor in series with the speaker results in no audio output.

Is there a better way to amplify the PWM signal and block the DC component?

The PWM signal ranges from 0-5V (square wave) with a frequency of ~30Khz.

Comment: Here's a discussion about a speaker hookup for Arduino: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=21485.0

Comment: Looking at the circuit he has, if the MOSFET stays switched on, there will be (12V)^2 * 33 ohm = 4.36 W dissipated by the resistor. Isn't that enough to fry most resistors? I guess in the common case, the average power would be 1/2 that (2.18 W), but that still seems high. Also, I need to run my amp from the same +5V power source the Arduino uses -- I can't use a separate +12V supply.

Comment: Since you're driving your audio amp with PWM you'll want to google "class D amplifier".

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Yep, I did that. I think I need the "output stage" of the class D amplifier, since the signal is already a square wave (the input stage of the class D converts from AC => square wave). However, I can't really find a good example. For instance, most of the schemes I found assume no DC bias, which my circuit has (more-or-less +2.5 DC bias). Basically, I've tried to use the MOSFET as a switch to generate a square wave with greater current than the input signal, but still can't get it loud enough if I decouple the speaker with a capacitor.

Comment: Also, many of the class D schematics I've found use a negative supply and 2 MOSFETS in push-pull configuration. I don't have a negative supply -- only a +5V rail.

Comment: Just use your +5V instead of the separate 12V. Also, why are you saying that the MOSFET will stay on all the time? You're using PWM to control it, right?

Comment: @alexx OK, I tried the circuit from the link you gave with +5V rail (instead of +12V), but the speaker isn't as loud as simply putting the speaker in series without a DC-blocking capacitor. I'm using PWM, but what if the software leaves the output for the PWM pin high for a long time? This will fry the hardware. I want to avoid a circuit that would fry the hardware if the PWM pin is left high.

Comment: You will need a push pull configuration then. You may want to look a these half-bridge MOSFET driver ICs.

Comment: One issue: Tie +5V to speaker +, speaker - to MOSFET drain, MOSFET source to gnd. In other words, use your n-channel MOSFET as a low-side driver, not high-side. The voltage drop across your speaker is preventing your MOSFET from turning fully ON (Vgs too low).

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do a complimentry drive for your proposed book up .If you do this then you can capacitively couple your speaker.Remember that the DCR of a 8 ohm speaker is approx 6 ohms . This rough ratio doesnt change much with speaker impedence.You could connect a couple of logic level fets in the CMOS configuration or you could use a grunty mosfet driver chip that say has an on resistance of 1 ohm.